# Actualizar dos tablas al mismo tiempo laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando con laravel 6

Tengo 2 tablas:

procesos: id, user_id, date_membership

usuarios: id, name, email, membership(enum con 2 opciones: estandar y anual)

La relacion es de un usuario puede tener muchos procesos y un proceso solo debe tener un usuario

Lo que quiero hacer es que al momento de actualizar el usuario en el campo enum de membership se editen todas las fechas de todos los procesos que tenga ese usuario a través de user_id

la membership estandar cambia el date_membership a 3 meses a partir de hoy y el anual cambia el date_membership a un a partir de hoy

Controlador Usuarios:

```
$usuario = User::find($id);

$usuario->name                  = $request->name;
$usuario->email                 = $request->email;
$usuario->membership            = $request->membership;

if($usuario->save()){
  return redirect('/home');
}
```

He intentado con:

```
$usuario = User::find($id);
$process = Process::select('date_membership')->where('claimant_id', $id);

$usuario->name                  = $request->name;
$usuario->email                 = $request->email;

if($request->membership == 'estandar'){
    $usuario->membership        = $request->membership;
    $process->date_membership = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 month'));
}else{
    $usuario->membership        = $request->membership;
    $process->date_membership = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year'));
}

if($usuario->save()){
  return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: En teoría process es un array de elementos proceso que son del usuario, no? Entonces vas a tener que recorrerlos y asignarles a todos la fecha que corresponda... Mira usar un foreach y luego a cada process hazle un save. No es lo más óptimo, pero al menos debería solucionarte el problema

Comment: podrias darme un ejemplo, porfa?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con eso que intentaste?¿Te dá algún error? ¿Tienes definidas en los modelos las relaciones entre User y Process?

Comment: no se actualizan las fechas de los procesos, solo actualiza el usuario

Comment: pero solo estas salvando el usuario... has probado con $process->save() ?

Comment: O algo así puede ser `$process->update([ 'date_membership' => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year') ) ]);`

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!